# deleting comma from particular cell data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 5003×2 cell array as per the image.

[image]

To be able to plot column1 vs column2, I need to remove all the end commas from column1.

I was trying by converting every data into a string and finding the comma 
position using 'strfind':

```
s              = result1(1,1);
s1             = strfind(s,',');
updated_result = s(1:(s1-1));
result1(1,1)   = updated_result;
```

but getting this error every time:

> Undefined operator '-' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another one-liner:

```
s(:,1) = strrep(s(:,1), ',', '');
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str2num` to convert the strings in the first column to numbers. For example:

```
% create an example cell array
s = {'4.28275e-006,', 126.923  ; 
    '4.28043e-006,' , 128.037  ;
    '4.2781e-006,'  , 129.009  ; 
    '4.27578e-006,' , 129.634   };

% extract the two columns
x = str2num([s{:,1}]);
y = [s{:,2}];

% plot
figure;
plot(x, y);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Never thought str2num can handle a 'comma'' too

Answer (score 0):

To strip characters from a string, you can just use the characters' indices... So if your comma is always at the end of a string, you could use

```
str = '4.1234e-006,' ;

str(1:length(str)-1) 

>> ans = '4.1234e-006'
```

To use this in your situation, it might be quickest to use a simple loop

```
for j = 1:5003

    s{j, 1}( 1 : length(s{j, 1})-1 ) ;

end
```

In this case, aksadv's answer using `str2num` is probably more elegant, but worth noting that strings are easily indexed like arrays.